# How do I create a new environment change through PowerShell WMI in a new process

Tags: wmi, powershell-2.0

I have same code.
How to pass a new environment change when creating a new process through WMI  ($ai.EnvironmentVariables = ?)
My example does not work, I issue Invalid parameter (21)

```
$procClass=[WMICLass]"win32_processstartup"
    $ai = $procClass.createinstance()
    $ai.ShowWindow = 1
    $ai.EnvironmentVariables = @('name', 'testvar')
    $ai.X = 0
    $ai.Y = 0
    $wmiclass = [wmiclass]"win32_process"
    $wmiMethodParameters = $wmiclass.psbase.GetMethodParameters("Create")
    $wmiMethodParameters.CommandLine = "test "
    $wmiMethodParameters.CurrentDirectory = "."
    $wmiMethodParameters.ProcessStartupInformation = $ai
    $pInfoCreate = $wmiclass.psbase.InvokeMethod("Create",$wmiMethodParameters,$null);
    $tempId = $pInfoCreate.ProcessId
    $pInfoObject = get-WmiObject -query "select * from win32_process where processid=$tempId"
```

Comment: Any reason you're using WMI here, instead of .NET's `System.Diagnostics.Process` class? `ProcessStartInfo` has an `EnvironmentVariables` property that would be easy to use from PowerShell.

Comment: Through System. Diagnostics. Process I did it without problems, for the purpose I want to implement the same only through WMI

Comment: My point is that there appears to be no benefit here to using WMI, hence my question. If you have to use WMI specifically for some reason, because it allows you to do something the `Process` class won't, that would be good to have as context. Otherwise, you're just making things harder for no gain. The docs do not specify what format `EnvironmentVariables` takes, for example; I'd imagine they must be strings of the form `var=value`, but that's speculation.

Comment: EnvironmentVariables Property System.String[] EnvironmentVariables {get;set;}.I don't understand how to make System. String [] in PowerShell. It is possible to pass there only a hash-table. What causes Invalid parameter (21)

Comment: I'm talking [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-processstartup). Yes, it's a `string[]`, but that doesn't tell you what those strings should *contain*. An environment variable has a name and a value. In the code above, you're passing individual tokens, which is almost certainly not right. Try `@('testvar=value')`. Hence my recommendation to just use `Process`, because it has no such ambiguity.

Comment: If done so too causes Invalid parameter (21)
$props = @{
name = 'test'
VariableValue = 'test VariableValue'
UserName = $env:username
}
$object = new-object psobject -Property $props  
 
$procClass=[WMICLass]"win32_processstartup"
$envClass=[WMICLass]"Win32_Environment"
$ai = $procClass.createinstance()
$ei = $envClass.createinstance()
$ai.ShowWindow = 1
$ai.EnvironmentVariables = $object

The problem is not in WMI itself but in PowerShell, exactly how to pass the parameter

Comment: I have already studied all these structures of process creation, tried both hash-table and array and turned psobject, throws wrong parameter error

Comment: Just tried it; `$ai.EnvironmentVariables = @('name=testvar')` works correctly (when invoking `cmd`, you can check the results with `set`). If that doesn't work for you (or leaving out that line entirely) your problem may be unrelated to environment variables.

Comment: I check in  $wmiMethodParameters.CommandLine = "powershell.exe -NoExit -c Get-ChildItem Env: ;  sleep -s 10"  
my new process crash

Comment: of CMD works thanks, but when the creation turned the process, it falls

Comment: I figured out what's the problem there need in place with a new variable pass yet  scope local env. Now left to come up with how to do it) Thank you very much for the help

Comment: `$v = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables().Clone(); $v["var"] = "val" ; $v.GetEnumerator() |% { $_.Key + "=" + $_.Value }`; something along those lines. Some escaping may be necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help